# onclick event not running, code sequence not correct

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The code below runs as far as `alert("click on extra image on the left")` then it does nothing upon clicking on the extra image that is added to the left div. Upon clicking on the extra image (`id="extraImage"`) I would like JS to change the color of the "extraImage" element to red. Also, I need to change the sequence in which the code is executed and run the `alert("click on extra image on the left")` AFTER pictures have been added. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="containerLeft">
        </div>
        <div id="containerRight">
        </div>

        <script>
            var i = 1
            var pocetSmilikov = prompt("enter number of smiley faces");
            alert("i will add" + pocetSmilikov);
            while (i <= pocetSmilikov)
            {
                insert();
                i++;
            }

            insertExtraToLeft();

            function insert() {
                var imgDestination = document.getElementById("containerRight");
                var imgAdded = document.createElement("img");
                imgAdded.src = "smiley.png";
                imgDestination.appendChild(imgAdded);
                var left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1) + "px";
                var top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1) + "px";
                var imagestyle = imgAdded.style;
                imagestyle.position = "relative";
                imagestyle.top = top;
                imagestyle.left = left;

                var the_node = document.getElementById("containerRight").lastChild;
                var the_clone = the_node.cloneNode(true);
                document.getElementById("containerLeft").appendChild(the_clone);
            }


            function insertExtraToLeft() {
                var imgDestinationExtra = document.getElementById("containerLeft");
                var imgAddedExtra = document.createElement("img");
                imgAddedExtra.src = "smiley.png";
                imgAddedExtra.id = "extraImage"
                imgDestinationExtra.appendChild(imgAddedExtra);
                var left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1) + "px";
                var top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1) + "px";
                var imagestyle = imgAddedExtra.style;
                imagestyle.position = "relative";
                imagestyle.top = top;
                imagestyle.left = left;
            }

            alert("click on extra image on the left");

            extraImage.onclick = extraImgFound();


            function extraImgFound() {
                document.getElementById("extraImage").style.color = "red";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `extraImage.onclick = extraImgFound;` DO NOT CALL the function (with `()`) unless the function itself returns a function to bind to the handler.

Comment: I removed parenthesis and re-run but still nothing happens when I click on the extra image that has been added by the code...

Comment: extraImage is not defined?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`extraImage` is not defined anywhere. Add `imgAddedExtra.onclick = extraImgFound();` in your `insertExtraToLeft()` function.

Try:

```
function insertExtraToLeft()
{
    var imgDestinationExtra = document.getElementById("containerLeft");
    var imgAddedExtra = document.createElement("img");
    imgAddedExtra.src = "smiley.png";
    imgAddedExtra.id ="extraImage"
    imgDestinationExtra.appendChild(imgAddedExtra);

    imgAddedExtra.onclick = extraImgFound();

    var left = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1)+"px";
    var top = Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1)+"px";
    var imagestyle = imgAddedExtra.style;
    imagestyle.position = "relative";
    imagestyle.top = top;
    imagestyle.left = left;
}
```